# Redirect to selected Item of Navbar after refreshing without scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I try to highlight the selected value of the navbar after refreshing the page. I did it using `localStorage`.It is working. But now when I click a bottom element then the scroll of the Navbar always goes to up. I want to Redirect it to the selected value after refreshing(Without scrolling).

This is my navbar elements loading `div`. This `@{Html.RenderAction("GenarateMenuByUser", "Menu", new { area = "" });}` load  elemets to the NavBar from controller.It has 40 elements.

```
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <div style="max-height: 100%;">
                <ul class="sidebar-nav" style="max-height: 85%; overflow-x: auto;">
                    <li class="sidebar-brand">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/user-icon.png")">
                            @*<span>@User.Identity.Name</span>*@
                            <span id="logusername">@displayName</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    @{Html.RenderAction("GenarateMenuByUser", "Menu", new { area = "" });}
                </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
```

This is the code to highlight the selected values in `$(document).ready(function ()`:

```
 $(".sidebar-nav li a").click(function () {
             var id = $(this).attr("id");
             console.log('id :' + id);

            $('#' + id).siblings().find(".active").removeClass("active");
            $('#' + id).addClass("active");
            localStorage.setItem("selectedolditem", id);
        });

        var selectedolditem = localStorage.getItem('selectedolditem');
        console.log('selectedolditem :' + selectedolditem);
        if (selectedolditem != null) {
            $('#' + selectedolditem).siblings().find(".active").removeClass("active");
            $('#' + selectedolditem).addClass("active");
        }
```

***So help me to redirect the Navbar to the selected element when clicking the bottom element then refreshing the page(avoid scrolling up after refreshing)***

[image: Inspection of the navbar elements]